# Error 'Has not wait the lock' using Yii2 Queue extension and Postgres 10.4

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, queue, locking

I've developed a project in yii2 that uses the yiisoft / yii2-queue extension. This extension stores orders to export very large CSVs.
The exported CSVs work correctly but from time to time it throws the exception of the image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rgms.png

I think it may be because of the postgres version I've working with: PostgreSQL 10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90 + 1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18 + deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516 , 64-bit

I have read that for version 9.4 it works.
The configuration of the extension that I have is the following:

```
'components' => [
    'queue' => [
        'class' => \yii\queue\db\Queue::class,
        'tableName' => '{{%queue}}', // Table name
        'channel' => 'default', // Queue channel key
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        'mutex' => [
            'class' => \yii\mutex\PgsqlMutex::class,
            'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        ],
        'mutexTimeout' => 0,
    ],
]
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 'mutexTimeout' => 0,
> ```

This is probably the reason. It means that queue will try acquire mutex once, and if it fails (which may be quite likely on busy queue) it will throw this exception.

[I added](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/16839) support for timeout in `PgsqlMutex`, but there was no release with this feature yet. I suggest to use `master` branch of `yiisoft/yii2` package and set `mutexTimeout` to non-zero value.

Comment: thanks for the idea.
We have been testing the solution. We have removed the _mutexTimeout_ parameter and we have also set it to 3, but time to time the error occurs in both cases.
It seems that the error does not have to do with the export function since the error occurs in a "random" way.
We will investigate more to see if we find the solution.
Any other idea is welcome. :)

Comment: DB queue may be quite slow if you have many queued jobs (at least it was slow on MySQL in my case) - it may result such errors if you have multiple workers on busy queue. Also `PgsqlMutex` is far from perfect, since it does not really wait for the lock, it just retries multiple times until timeout is reached - if you don't have lucky  each try may fail even if there were time frames whether lock could be acquired. You may try `MysqlMutex`, it should be more reliable in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by change two methods in **vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/db/Queue.php** - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/pull/362/files
Code:

```
/**
 * @param array $payload
 */
protected function release($payload)
{
    $mutex = $this->mutex->acquire(__CLASS__ . $this->channel, $this->mutexTimeout);

    try {
        if ($this->deleteReleased) {
            $this->db->createCommand()->delete(
                $this->tableName,
                ['id' => $payload['id']]
            )->execute();
        } else {
            $this->db->createCommand()->update(
                $this->tableName,
                ['done_at' => time()],
                ['id' => $payload['id']]
            )->execute();
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        \Yii::error($e->getMessage());
    } finally {
        if ($mutex) {
            $this->mutex->release(__CLASS__ . $this->channel);
        } else {
            \Yii::warning('Queue->release() Has not waited the lock');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Moves expired messages into waiting list.
 */
private function moveExpired()
{
    if ($this->reserveTime !== time()) {
        $this->reserveTime = time();
        $this->db->createCommand()->update(
            $this->tableName,
            ['reserved_at' => null],
            '[[reserved_at]] < :time - [[ttr]] and [[reserved_at]] is not null and [[done_at]] is null',
            [':time' => $this->reserveTime]
        )->execute();
    }
}
```